# Vue - access input value inside the input's attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is is possible to access `input`s value inside it's definition/attribute?

For example, if you want an input to be green if not empty but you don't want to use `Vue.data`.

Like this:

```
<v-text-field background-color="'green' ? <THISVAL> : 'red'"></v-text-field>
```

Or do I need `v-model` and variable defined in the `Vue.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need `v-model` and variable defined in the `Vue.data`.

Why? Remember that vue uses virtual DOM. When this template is being processed for the first time, no actual element is present in DOM, to be access via `this`.
It needs to know what to render into DOM beforehand.

---

There is [`component-template-refs`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) to gain references to actual HTML elements, but these references are assigned after the component is mount, and not needed for use cases like this